# Merge two or more tables checking the unique value using python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am a beginner with Python.
I have to check 2 or 3 tables and see if some data is missing.
The data are `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.
I have these tables:

```
start   end val accn    fy  fp  form    filed   frame
0   2016-01-01  2016-12-31  90272000000 0001652044-19-000004    2018    FY  10-K    2019-02-05  CY2016
6   2017-01-01  2017-12-31  110855000000    0001652044-19-000004    2018    FY  10-K    2019-02-05  NaN
7   2017-01-01  2017-12-31  110855000000    0001652044-20-000008    2019    FY  10-K    2020-02-04  CY2017
18  2018-01-01  2018-12-31  136819000000    0001652044-19-000004    2018    FY  10-K    2019-02-05  NaN
19  2018-01-01  2018-12-31  136819000000    0001652044-20-000008    2019    FY  10-K    2020-02-04  CY2018
30  2019-01-01  2019-12-31  161857000000    0001652044-20-000008    2019    FY  10-K    2020-02-04  CY2019
41  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  182527000000    0001652044-23-000016    2022    FY  10-K    2023-02-03  CY2020
52  2021-01-01  2021-12-31  257637000000    0001652044-23-000016    2022    FY  10-K    2023-02-03  CY2021
61  2022-01-01  2022-12-31  282836000000    0001652044-23-000016    2022    FY  10-K    2023-02-03  CY2022
```

and

```
start   end val accn    fy  fp  form    filed   frame
0   2006-12-31  2007-12-29  39474000000 0001193125-10-036385    2009    FY  10-K    2010-02-22  CY2007
4   2007-12-30  2008-12-27  43251000000 0001193125-11-040427    2010    FY  10-K    2011-02-18  NaN
5   2007-12-30  2008-12-27  43251000000 0001193125-10-036385    2009    FY  10-K    2010-02-22  NaN
13  2008-12-28  2009-12-26  43232000000 0001193125-12-081822    2011    FY  10-K    2012-02-27  CY2009
15  2008-12-28  2009-12-26  43232000000 0001193125-11-040427    2010    FY  10-K    2011-02-18  NaN
16  2008-12-28  2009-12-26  43232000000 0001193125-10-036385    2009    FY  10-K    2010-02-22  NaN
27  2009-12-27  2010-12-25  57838000000 0001445305-13-000278    2012    FY  10-K    2013-02-21  CY2010
28  2009-12-27  2010-12-25  57838000000 0001193125-12-081822    2011    FY  10-K    2012-02-27  NaN
30  2009-12-27  2010-12-25  57838000000 0001193125-11-040427    2010    FY  10-K    2011-02-18  NaN
41  2010-12-26  2011-12-31  66504000000 0001445305-13-000278    2012    FY  10-K    2013-02-21  NaN
42  2010-12-26  2011-12-31  66504000000 0001193125-12-081822    2011    FY  10-K    2012-02-27  NaN
43  2010-12-26  2011-12-31  66504000000 0000077476-14-000007    2013    FY  10-K    2014-02-14  CY2011
54  2012-01-01  2012-12-29  65492000000 0001445305-13-000278    2012    FY  10-K    2013-02-21  NaN
56  2012-01-01  2012-12-29  65492000000 0000077476-15-000012    2014    FY  10-K    2015-02-12  NaN
57  2012-01-01  2012-12-29  65492000000 0000077476-14-000007    2013    FY  10-K    2014-02-14  NaN
68  2012-12-30  2013-12-28  66415000000 0000077476-16-000066    2015    FY  10-K    2016-02-11  CY2013
70  2012-12-30  2013-12-28  66415000000 0000077476-15-000012    2014    FY  10-K    2015-02-12  NaN
71  2012-12-30  2013-12-28  66415000000 0000077476-14-000007    2013    FY  10-K    2014-02-14  NaN
82  2013-12-29  2014-12-27  66683000000 0000077476-17-000010    2016    FY  10-K    2017-02-15  CY2014
83  2013-12-29  2014-12-27  66683000000 0000077476-16-000066    2015    FY  10-K    2016-02-11  NaN
85  2013-12-29  2014-12-27  66683000000 0000077476-15-000012    2014    FY  10-K    2015-02-12  NaN
96  2014-12-28  2015-12-26  63056000000 0000077476-18-000012    2017    FY  10-K    2018-02-13  CY2015
97  2014-12-28  2015-12-26  63056000000 0000077476-17-000010    2016    FY  10-K    2017-02-15  NaN
98  2014-12-28  2015-12-26  63056000000 0000077476-16-000066    2015    FY  10-K    2016-02-11  NaN
109 2015-12-27  2016-12-31  62799000000 0000077476-18-000012    2017    FY  10-K    2018-02-13  CY2016
110 2015-12-27  2016-12-31  62799000000 0000077476-17-000010    2016    FY  10-K    2017-02-15  NaN
117 2017-01-01  2017-12-30  63525000000 0000077476-18-000012    2017    FY  10-K    2018-02-13  CY2017
```

So the target is to check and merge the data from all years.
So basically I have to check the 2 tables and create a new table with all CY Years.
For example the first table start from 2016, but the second from 2007. So I need to create a table with `val` and `frame` merged and unique values. The table basically should have all years found from an API.

Example result:

```
39474000000 2007
43232000000  2009
57838000000 2010
...
110855000000     2017
etc etc
```

There is a thing I have to check if both tables contain data for `the same year`(example `2017`), then I have to check which `val` is bigger and insert this in the new table.
How can  I do an iter for loo year by year and check the val value between the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore rows where `frame` is `NaN`, you can simply concat your filtered dfs and group by `frame` before applying `max`:

```py
df1 = df1.dropna(subset='frame')[['val', 'frame']]
df2 = df2.dropna(subset='frame')[['val', 'frame']]

pd.concat([
    df1[~df1['frame'].str.contains('Q')], 
    df2[~df2['frame'].str.contains('Q')]
]).groupby('frame').max()
```

Output:

```
                 val
frame
CY2007   39474000000
CY2009   43232000000
CY2010   57838000000
CY2011   66504000000
CY2013   66415000000
CY2014   66683000000
CY2015   63056000000
CY2016   90272000000
CY2017  110855000000
CY2018  136819000000
CY2019  161857000000
CY2020  182527000000
CY2021  257637000000
CY2022  282836000000
```

Edit: excluding `frame` cells containing `'Q'`.

Comment: i forgot to say that the frame contains also other values as 
CY2007 
CY2008 
CY2008Q2 
CY2008Q3 
I just need to have CYXXX not Q

Comment: How i drop the CYxxxQx?